# $state.go is not redirecting in ui-router AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How to call ui-view from another Controller in AngularJS

This is my sample program. Actually in here I am using nested ui-view. The problem is when I click the submit
button initially it works fine and show an alert SampleController

But again i clicked it doesnt got to SampleController why?

I need to go to that controller when i click on submit button

Is it any error on my code.Please check it my stateProvider too.I am a new starter in AngularJS

Plese correct me  Thank you...

```
var app=angular.module('TestApp', ['angular.filter','ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('category', {
        views : {   
            "body" : {
                url : '/category',
                templateUrl : 'category.html',
                controller : 'TestController'
            }
        }       
    })
    .state('category.subcategory', {
        url : '/subcategory',
        views : {                              
            "subbody@category" : {
                templateUrl : 'sample.html',
                controller : 'SampleController'              
            }
        }
    })
});

app.controller('MainController', MainController);
function MainController($scope,$state) {
    alert("This is MainController") 
    $scope.getCategory=function(){
        $state.go('category');
    }
}

app.controller('TestController', TestController);
function TestController($scope, $state){    
    $scope.getData=function() {
        alert("Call to Sample Controller")
        $state.go('.subcategory');
    }
}

app.controller('SampleController', SampleController);
function SampleController($scope,$state) {
    alert("This is SampleController")
}
```

This is my sample HTML files
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-ui-router.js"></script>    
        <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <a href="#" ng-click="getCategory()">Click to Category</a>
        <div ui-view="body">
            <div ui-view="subbody"></div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

category.html

```
 <div>      
   <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" ng-click="getData()" />
   <div ui-view="subbody"></div>
 </div>
```

sample.html

```
 <div>
    Sample Controller
</div>
```

I need to hit SampleController when i click submit button

Comment: Sure you don't just need $state.go('category.subcategory'); instead of $state.go('.subcategory');?

Comment: Your code is working fine as the way you configured. I guess, you are looking for some other functionality. Can you explain your question in detail manner?

Comment: @codeinja Its working fine only one once when you click again in submit button it cannot hit the sample controller you just check it

Comment: I need when i click summit button at any time I need an alert in SampleController

Comment: Did you see that 'This is SampleController" in Sample Contr0ller

Comment: Initially its working fine but after again you just clcik that its not working?

Comment: @Matt Searles I didnt get any alert after changing $state.go('category.subcategory'); instead of $state.go('.subcategory');

Comment: Actually my need is when i click submit button SampleController is refreshed and give an alert ""This is SampleController''. But its work only one time

Comment: @Satej S I cant understsand any problem in my code

Comment: @SatejS Please help me I dont know how to set up plunker I am a student newly in this angularJs ad all.Please consider me.Actullay i posted entire code you just paste it in eclipse its working fine.The only problem is when i submit again I didnt got any alert in Samplecontroller thats my problem

Comment: Actually you see i added one alert in Sample Controller you see that.Initially when i submit got an alert.But again click submit i coudnt

Comment: @SatejS In my project that submit button  portion contains two select boxes category and subcategory .Based on that catgeory
  and subcategory i need to show details on the SampleController.So refreshing only done by SampleController.

Comment: @codeninja.js In my project that submit button  portion contains two select boxes category and subcategory .Based on that catgeory
  and subcategory i need to show details on the SampleController.So refreshing only done by SampleController.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$state.go(".subcategory", null, { reload : true });
```

Comment: no sir its not Working In my project that submit button portion contains two select boxes category and subcategory .Based on that catgeory and subcategory i need to show details on the SampleController.

Comment: Hm, sounds like you should move the getData function into a service and have it populate a data field, inject the service into any or all of your controllers, bind the ui to the data field on the service, and ask the controller to refresh the data on the service.

Comment: Can you help me I am new in AngularJS Please support. I am doing my academic project.I am reallay stuck

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define one service and inject into controller. Then there is a chance to work.

Controller:

```js
app.controller('TestController', TestController);

function TestController($scope, mainService) {
  $scope.getData = function() {
    mainService.getDetails();
    //$state.go(.subcategory) //you can use here,If fails I have written in service(inject $state)
  };
}
```

Service:

```js
app.service('mainService', mainService)
mainService.$inject = ['$http', '$state'];

function mainService($http, $state) {

  this.getDetails = function() {
    console.log("Hai");
    $state.go(.subcategory);

  }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine only one once when you click again in submit button it cannot hit the sample controller you just check it .  In mu code also same..I need when i click again submit button i need to get an alert ''This is Sample Controller'''  Ashokji check it that.Please help me bhai

Comment: In service function you are uising UserService  I correct it mainService but not working ji

Comment: You just copied my code to eclipse and run it please.Initially alert is getting from SampleController but again i click to that submit button i couldnt  get that alert